# What artifact managers are available in GCP?

Tags: artifactory, virtualization, gcp, nexus

I use Artifactory and Nexus3, but I wonder what artifact manager could be used in GCP? Is there a managed artifact manager or do I have to run one myself in a VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the artifacts in question are docker images then the recommended artifact management solution is the [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/), well integrated with other GCP products producing and/or using such images.

AFAIK they don't have a real artifact manager for other kinds of artifacts, they suggest the rather general purpose Cloud Storage for that. You can find an example of such use in the [Quickstart for Go](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-go) guide. Most likely not what you're looking for:

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/'
    paths: ['hello']
```

Answer (score 2):

A new service have been released this year called [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry)